# Active noise cancellation

Tags: delphi, audio, noise, cancellation

I have programed a voice recognition program and I am have problems with the mic hearing me, over the computer playing music. I need software that can filter out the sound leaving the speakers from the sound entering the mic.

Is there software or a component (for Delphi) that would solve my problem?

Comment: You would need to capture the noise profile in a kind of fft monitor ( for example it would define that band 36, 67, 123, ..., need to be reduced by x db) make a fft filter with this profile and apply it to your signal. I donwvoted because this is a bit off- topic. You ask for a software or a component with no preliminary work. And maybe it fits more in QA site 'Signal processing' ?

Comment: As a tip, to cancel out a noise, you can play it over top of itself with the phase reversed.

Comment: I've been searching for a while and all I found was non-sense! Then this. This is the actual case! May I ask, how did it work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to capture:

1. computer output
2. mic. input

Then you need to find two parameters, depending of your mic. location and sound system delay. This two parameter is n-delay and k-amplify.

```
Stream1[t+n]*k=Stream2[t]
```

Where t = time. When you find this parameter then your resulting Stream, only  speek mic. input will be

```
Stream2[t]-Stream1[t+n]*k=MusicReductionStream[t]
```

Comment: Really like this neat solution. The `n` in this equation depends on buffer size of the audio out, i.e. the latency of the output.

Comment: You could eradicate the need for knowing `n` here by creating your own buffer of `x` amount of sample frames, before sending to the audio out buffer itself. This would be good, although it might make the latency time intolerable to the end-user.

Comment: This won't work very well, as the impulse response of the system is unlikely to be a single delay tap.  The sound will spread out in time due to reflections in the room, speaker phase response, and etc.

Comment: Indeed, this is a bit of a naive approach. Given the right n and k in a non-changing environment, you can probably get rid of a large portion of the feedback, but in a real life situation this formula alone is not going to work like the feedback cancellation that you're used to on skype or your mobile phone.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to do what [noise canceling microphones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-canceling_microphone) do.  These systems use at least one extra microphone to calculate the difference between "surrounding noise" and the noise that is aimed directly at the microphone (the speech it has to register).  I don't think you can reliably obtain the same effect with a software-only solution.

A first step would obviously be to turn music down :-)

Comment: -1: yours is a comment, not an answer.  The request was for a software solution to remove sound being generated by the computer from the sound it receives.

Comment: @Argalatyr But this is valid point, noise cancellation is extremely hard to do without extra information, which noise cancellation microphone has.

Comment: @Argalatyr I see your point, and I hesitated some time between an answer and a comment. However, the fact that the problem is very hard to correctly solve in software combined with the incredible simplicity of the hardware solution (a second mike, or an off the shelf noise cancelling one costing not much) made me decide to formulate it as an answer to the question. But I agree it's somewhat hazy..

Comment: The Voice recognition program is suppose to control itunes. so turning down the music is not much of an option.

Comment: While a microphone picking up the ambient noise would be /ideal/, having the SOURCE of the ambient noise (what's being sent out through the speakers) will allow for significant (if imperfect) cancellation. It is not an unreasonable request.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the **AsioVST** library.

- 100% open source Delphi code
- Free
- Very complete
- Active (support for xe2 / x64 is being added for example)

Under `Examples\Plugins\Crosstalk Cancellation\` you'll find the source code for a plugin that probably does what you're looking for.

[image: Screenshot]

The magic happens in [DAV_DspCrosstalkCancellation.pas](http://delphiasiovst.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/delphiasiovst/trunk/Source/DSP/DAV_DspCrosstalkCancellation.pas?revision=1678&view=markup).

Answer (score 1):

I think the speex pre-processor has an echo-cancellation feature. You'll need to feed it the audio data you recorded, and the audio you want to cancel, and it'll try to remove it.

The main problem is finding out what audio your computer plays. Not sure if there is a good API for that.

It also has a noise reduction feature, and voice activity detection. You can compile it as a dll, and then write a delphi header.

Answer (score 1):

You need to estimate the impulse response of the speaker and room, etc., which can change with exact speaker and mic positioning and the size and contents of the room, etc., as well as knowing/estimating the system delay.

If the person or the mic are moveable, the impulse response and delay will need to be continually re-estimated.

Once you have estimated the impulse response, you can convolve it with the output signal and try subtract delayed versions of the result from the mic input until you can null silent portions of the speech input.  Cross correlation might be useful for estimating the delay.